# How can I modify array with user input (displayed with table in html)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I just want to add user-input value to empty array.
The process that I want is that 
1. user input some number on web ( designed with html table tag)
2. user-input value added to empty array

ex. empty arr = [[],[]]
user input = 1  2
             3  4

then empty arr = [[1,2],[3,4]]

my code is below, i don't understand what's wrong

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Javascript HW1</title>
    <Style>
        table,th,td{
            border:1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </Style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:40%; float:left;">
        <table id="tb1">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">A_Matrix</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="00" oninput="fill_A(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="01" oninput="fill_A(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="02" oninput="fill_A(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="03" oninput="fill_A(this)">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="10" oninput="fill_A(this)">

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="11" oninput="fill_A(this)">

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="12" oninput="fill_A(this)">

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="13" oninput="fill_A(this)">

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="20" oninput="fill_A(this)">

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="21"oninput="fill_A(this)">

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="22" oninput="fill_A(this)">

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="23" oninput="fill_A(this)">

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="30" oninput="fill_A(this)">

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="31" oninput="fill_A(this)">

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="32" oninput="fill_A(this)">

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="33" oninput="fill_A(this)">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div style="width:40%; float:right;">
        <table id="tb2">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">B_Matrix</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="00" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="01" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="02" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="03" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="10" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="11" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="12" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="13" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="20" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="21" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="22" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="23" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="30" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="31" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="32" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="33" oninput="fill_B(this)">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br>

        <input type="button" id="res" value="Calculate matrix multiplication (A*B)" />


</body>
<script src="./matrix_mul.js"></script>
</html>




function matrix_mul(m1, m2) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
        result[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < m2[0].length; j++) {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var k = 0; k < m1[0].length; k++) {
                sum += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
            }
            result[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function display(m) {
    for (var r = 0; r < m.length; ++r) {
      document.write('&nbsp;&nbsp;'+m[r].join(' ')+'<br />');
    }
}

var A_Matrix = [[],[],[],[]];
var B_Matrix = [[],[],[],[]];


function fill_A(e){
    var K = 
document.getElementById(e.getAttribute('id')).getAttribute('id');
    var i = Number(K.substring(0,1));
    var j = Number(K.substring(1,2));
    A_Matrix[i][j] = Number(document.getElementById(K).value);
}

function fill_B(f){
    var a = 
document.getElementById(f.getAttribute('id')).getAttribute('id');
    var b = Number(a.substring(0,1));
    var c = Number(a.substring(1,2));
    B_Matrix[b][c] = Number(document.getElementById(a).value);
}

var aa = document.getElementById('res');
aa.addEventListener('click', function(){
var result = matrix_mul(A_Matrix, B_Matrix);
display(result);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

UPD: matrix filling is correct, while matrix multiplication is performed on page loading. Right now on button click only display works. Calculations are performed on page loading when first matrix is empty. To perform calculation only after button is clicked, move line

```
var result = matrix_mul(A_Matrix, B_Matrix);
```

inside the function for button e.g.:

```
aa.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
  var result = matrix_mul(A_Matrix, B_Matrix);
  display(result);
})
```

Comment: Hmmm.. still i don’t understand... my id in html is 00,01,02,03,... like this! Isn’t it proper for index in 2d array???

Comment: And i just briefly explained in question, but my final goal is to make 4*4 table value into 2d 4*4 array!

Comment: So could you please explain in more details what you need as a result. What's the logic of placing digits from inputs to an array?

Comment: Okay. The process is like this. With the html table, user can see 4*4 table, and the user will input 4*4 elements, total 16 numbers. What I want to do is matrix multiplication with the values that user input on table. So I make the id of table like "00", "01", "02", ..., "33" so that i can use id as an index of 2d array. To chance the id as an index, i wrote 3 lines code in function fill(). To summarize, when user input 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4 in 4*4 table, then I want to make a 2d_array like [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]] so that i can do matrix multiplication.

Comment: And what's going wrong? I tried this with 4 lines of inputs and it works well. What's the problem?

Comment: I posted full code of js and html. Can you check what's wrong with my code? It's very simple code but i don't know why something is wrong... Just pretend B_Matrix is identity matrix. So when I enter  [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]] , then when I click the calculate button, the output should be  [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]] , but it appears as 4*4 'zero matrix'.

Comment: you perform matrix multiplication on page loading. At this moment A_MAtrix is filled with nulls. At button click you just display result that is calculated on page loading. move line `var result = matrix_mul(A_Matrix, B_Matrix);` inside the function for button e.g.: `aa.addEventListener('click', function(){ display(matrix_mul(A_Matrix, B_Matrix));}) `

Comment: Could you please mark an answer if it helps? thsnks.

Answer (score 0):

`[[],[]]` is not an empty array in JavaScript - this is an array with 2 nested array elements (i.e.: a matrix). A single array literal is defined simply like this: `[]`.

To answer your question you could simply use `Array.prototype.push` to add items to an array. For example:

```js
const inputEl = document.querySelector('input[type=\'text\']');
const buttonEl = document.querySelector('button');
const userInput = [];

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  userInput.push(inputEl.value);

  console.log(userInput);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button>Add to array</button>
```